# Python: how to have dynamicly generated function arguments without using an eval

Tags: python

I am trying to setup a system where users can submit an equation to be solved. I have a class, DP, which represents the full parameterization of the problem. A different class, dpsolver, takes a dp object, constructs the matrices, and will solve the problem.

When creating the DP object, one of the attributes is a function reference where the function is like this:

```
def equation1(r, tx, p, p_prime, k, k_prime, z, z_prime ):
    """ it is assumed all arguments are same sized ndarray or scalar"""
    inv = k_prime - 0.8 * k
    v = np.power(z_prime * inv, 0.75) * (1-tx) - p*tx + p_prime
    return(v)
```

r and tx are scalars defined in the DP object. p, p_prime, k, k_prime, z, z_prime are all numpy matrices which are constructed based on other information contained in the instantiation of the DP class. The DP class contains an OrderedDict which has p,k, and z as keys (in that order). p_prime, k_prime, and z_prime are all inferred by solver. My question is, what is the right way to call the equation1 function from solver. I want to that function as simple as possible, so other people can submit equations which can be easily integrated into this system.

I was thinking that using eval could work, or alternatively using lists and then using eval to unpack the list within equation1. What is the best way to do this without using eval? Or will eval be okay in terms of performance?

Comment: I'm confused.  How come you can't just *call that function with the arguments you've defined*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question:

> alternatively using lists and then using eval to unpack the list
>   within equation1

You may very well already be aware of this, but in case you're not, calling:

```
equation1(*list_of_parameters)
```

Does just this.

Similarly, doing

```
equation1(**dict_of_parameters)
```

Will expand a dict to keyword arguments.

Eval is there for a reason, but using it for metaprogramming is often a bad idea.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was not aware of this. This is my first Python project. Thanks for the help. What is this functionality called?

Comment: @stevejb - Um, honestly, I don't know... "Parameter expansion" maybe?  I'm not sure I've ever actually run across the "real" name for it...

Comment: @stevejb:  The closest thing to a special term for this is a word you already used in the text of your question:  *unpacking*.  See section 4.7.4 of the tutorial in the official Python docs.